# mysql Incorrect Information in File: (corrupt) error

Tags: mysql

I've recently suffered from a power outage on one of my monitoring servers at the office.
The result of that outage caused for some database tables to get corrupted.

I've successfully repaired 3-4 tables by using the "use_frm" option however there are still 3 that seem to be badly corrupted and are not responding to the mysql REPAIR command (with or without use_frm)

```
mysql> REPAIR TABLE poller_item;
+-------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------       ------------+
| Table             | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                    |
+-------------------+--------+----------+-------------------------------------------------  ---------+
| cacti.poller_item | repair | Error    | Incorrect information in file:    './cacti/poller_item.frm' |
| cacti.poller_item | repair | error    | Corrupt                                                      |
+-------------------+--------+----------+-------------------------------------------------  ---------+
```

In this scenario are there any other way to repair a table?

MySQL Version

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.49, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Incorrect information in file:    './cacti/poller_item.frm'
```

`.frm` file stores the table format. Try this:

- Stop MySQL
- Take the backup of `poller_item.frm`, `poller_item.MYD`, `poller_item.MYI`
- Drop the `poller_item` table
- Start MySQL
- Recreate `poller_item` table by using `CREATE TABLE` statement in
  [cacti.sql](http://www.cacti.net/downloads/patches/0.8.6h/pre-patched/cacti.sql)
  (uses the corresponding version that you're running)
- Stop MySQL
- Copy the `poller_item.MYD`, `poller_item.MYI` into the datadir
- Start MySQL again

Comment: This fixed the issue. It's important to note for future people experiencing this issue that after I had completed the above steps I also needed to do a `REPAIR TABLE poller_item use_frm;` Thanks!

Comment: @quanta I don't have .MYD & MYI. but have .ibd file so will those same steps work for innodb also

Answer (score 0):

take backup first and then try try MYISAMCHK(1):

```
myisamchk --recover tbl
myisamchk --save-recover tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in mariadb (mysql) for 5 tables "in use".

message after check or repair was

```
Incorrect information in file:    './tablename.frm'
Corrupted
```

In database folder, these frm files had 0 size. So, i stopped mariadb service and then just overwrite them with frm files from backup. Then I started again mariadb service and tables where fixed.
NOTICE: First, I tested this solution with a table that had only 1-2 rows of data, to be sure that it works. I had also azure backup, so if that didnt work, I could rollback to previous hour.

Good luck!